# XML namespace and variable element names

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2

My XML:

```
<root xmlns="mynamespace">

<measInfo measInfoId="CORE,SIP_session_statistics">

          <measType>CPUUSAGE</measType>
          <measType>CPUMEM</measType>
          <measType>SYSMEM</measType>

        <measValue measObjLdn='bsNo=18'>
          <r>1</r>
          <r>2</r>
          <r>3</r>
        </measValue>

        <measValue measObjLdn='bsNo=19'>
            <r>4</r>
            <r>5</r>
            <r>6</r>
        </measValue>
    </measInfo>
    <measInfo measInfoId="CORE,SIP_session_statistics">
           <measType>CPUUSAGE</measType>
          <measType>CPUMEM</measType>
          <measType>SYSMEM</measType>
        <measValue measObjLdn='bsNo=17'>
           <r>1</r>
          <r>2</r>
          <r>3</r>
        </measValue>
    </measInfo>

</root>
```

Obviously my requirement is similar my one of previous question but this time its kept in variable and with namespace problem as we know.

I want to get to the `<r>` element for particular `<measType>CPUUSAGE</measType>`

I have to store few things in variables:

```
my $ptag=measInfo;
my $ktag=measType;
my $vtag=measValue;
my $whr="CPUUSAGE";
my $mn="measObjLdn";
my $rng='bsNo=18';
```

I am using `$pos` to locate the right order of the `<r>` element.

```
for my $type_node ($conn->findnodes("//\*[name()='$ptag'][\*[name()='$ktag'][.='$whr']]")) {
    $pos = $type_node->findvalue("count(preceding-sibling::$ktag) + 1");
    $qry = <<"EOF";

..

/$mv[contains(concat(\@$ml, ','), '$rng')]

/r[$pos]

EOF

    for my $r_node ($type_node->findnodes($qry)) {
        $r_node->removeChildNodes;
        $r_node->appendText($new_value);
    }
}
```

Q> Nothing works. may be silly mistake????

Comment: Does it work if you remove the xmlns attribute on <root>?

Comment: Yes it does: Here is the code:

Comment: for my $type_node ($conn->findnodes("//${ptag}/${ktag}[.='$whr']")) {



    $pos = $type_node->findvalue("count(preceding-sibling::$ktag) + 1");
    $qry = <<"EOF";
..
/${mv}[contains(concat(\@$ms, ','), '$rng')]
/r[$pos]
EOF

    for my $r_node ($type_node->findnodes($qry)) {
        $r_node->removeChildNodes;
        $r_node->appendText($new_value);
    }
}

Comment: So now there are 2 problems with this. 1> How to resolve this with namesspace and 2>How to have exact match instead of contains()

Comment: No I am able to solve the second problem:   /${vtag}[\@$atag='$rng']

Comment: Lose the namespace. Why do you [need](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cargo-cult-programming.html) it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but maybe the namespace usage and xpath are helpful.

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $document = $parser->load_xml(location => $input_file);

my $xml_root = $document->documentElement();

my $xmlns_root = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml_root);

$xmlns_root->registerNs('mynamespace', 'mynamespace');

foreach my $type_node ($xmlns_root->findnodes('/mynamespace:root/mynamespace:measInfo[mynamespace:measType/text()="CPUUSAGE"]/mynamespace:measValue[@measObjLdn="bsNo=18"]/mynamespace:r[1]')) {
     print $type_node->textContent();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't use any of the variables it's suppose to use

Comment: thanks for the response Bob. But using hardcoded namespace does not seem very practical to me. The names spaces are not always known in advance in my project. Also its not solving my variable problem

Comment: All my variable problem is solved now. The only issue is the namespace. And I tried it as above but not resolving. There are posts in about namespace but its not resolving still.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIALLY RESOLVED:** Variable can be used now.

**PENDING:** NameSpace issue pending.

```
for my $type_node ($conn->findnodes("//${ptag}/${ktag}[.='$whr']")) { 

    $pos = $type_node->findvalue("count(preceding-sibling::$ktag) + 1");

    $qry = "../${vtag}[\@$atag='$rng']/r[$pos]";

    for my $r_node ($type_node->findnodes($qry)) {

        $r_node->removeChildNodes;

        $r_node->appendText($new_value);

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained why you "need" the namespace.  Quite likely, you don't.  If you have code that works with the namespace removed, then just pre-process the XML, as a string, to remove that pesky namespace attribute, and you're done.